# How to search a comma separated string from a comma separated string in column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a Comma separated string(Category) column in my db like the following:

```
|-------------------|------------------|
|         Id        |     Category     |
|-------------------|------------------|
|        1850       |      10,11       |
|-------------------|------------------|
|        1851       |      1,2,3       |
|-------------------|------------------|
```

And I am Passing a comma separated string like 1,11 to search from this table like the following but it's not giving me the results of i pass more than one values:

```
Declare @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(4000) = '11'
Select Id,ImageCategory from AppImage
WHERE (',' + RTRIM(ImageCategory) + ',')  LIKE '%,' + @SearchTerm + ',%'
```

If I Pass only one value like 1 or 11 then it gives the results. How can I pass multiple and get the results. I have half million records and 20 columns in this table so i need a good speed too.

Comment: Is it an 'or' or is it an 'and' if you have mutliple entries. And it also doesn't work for single values, since you would get a result if if you search '2' and the record contains '21,24'

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in the first place. With a properly normalized model you wouldn't have this problem. Do you have a chance to fix your data model?

Comment: I need to add 'or' and i have update the updated query so that it will return 2 if pass 2. Kindly check updated question. @Turo

Answer (score 1):

Fix your data model!  Storing multiple integers in a string is just wrong, wrong, wrong:

- Wrong because numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- Wrong because strings should only store one value.
- Wrong because SQL has poor string processing functions.
- Wrong because the data should be stored in *rows* not a single *column*.

Sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really bad decisions.

You can work around this.  SQL Server offers `string_split()`:

```
with input as (
      select value
      from string_split(@SearchTerm, ',') 
     )
select ai.*
from AppImage ai 
exists (select 1
        from string_split(ai.category)
        where value in (select i.value from input i)
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
Declare @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(4000) = '1,11'
declare @SearchTerm1 NVARCHAR(10)
declare @SearchTerm2 NVARCHAR(10)
set @SearchTerm1=left(@SearchTerm, charindex(',', @SearchTerm) - 1)
set @SearchTerm2=right(@SearchTerm, charindex(',', @SearchTerm))
Select Id,ImageCategory from AppImage
WHERE RTRIM(ImageCategory)  LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm1 + '%' or RTRIM(ImageCategory) like '%' + @SearchTerm2 + '%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I can have multiple comma separated values in parameter like 1,2,4,8,9,5,6,5,12,19...... so i can't create variables like that